# How work with 3rd-party @ConfigurationProperties @Bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, property-files

I use IntellijIdea and gradle. Gradle config:

```
...
apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-maven'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7'
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)
dependencies {
    ...
    optional group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor', version: '1.4.0.RELEASE'
}
```

Ok, for creating my own properties i need:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("own.prefix")
@Data
public class TestProps {
    public String field;
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TestProps.class)
public class AppConf {}
```

And after i rebuild project spring-boot-configuration-processor genereate new META-INFO, so in application.properties i can use own.prefix.field= and Spring see it.

But what should i do with 3rd party configuration class?
Docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html say:

> As well as using `@ConfigurationProperties` to annotate a class, you
>   can also use it on `@Bean` methods. This can be particularly useful
>   when you want to bind properties to third-party components that are
>   outside of your control.
>
> To configure a bean from the Environment properties, add
>   `@ConfigurationProperties` to its bean registration:
>
> ```
> @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
> @Bean
> public FooComponent fooComponent() {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> Any property defined with the foo prefix will be mapped onto that
>   FooComponent bean in a similar manner as the ConnectionProperties
>   example above.

Ok. Lets try. For example I declare bean like in gide (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/):

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SocialConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook.client")
    OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails facebook() {
        return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook.resource")
    ResourceServerProperties facebookResource() {
        return new ResourceServerProperties();
    }
}
```

But after rebuilding project property facebook.client and facebook.resource do not exist in my application.properties.

Also i tried add SocialConfig.class to

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SocialConfig.class)
public class AppConf {}
```

After rebuild it still not work.
And like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class AppConf {}
```

Still the same.

What am I doing wrong?
Also sorry for my English :)

Comment: What do you mean by "do not exist in my application.properties"? Are you saying that you don't have them as auto-complete values? You shouldn't rely on the auto-complete values as meaning that you can or can't add those properties to the configuration. The auto-complete is a best effort to reduce the memory of the developer on the naming of each property.

Is auto-complete capabilities the only concern you have or is there another issue you are trying to resolve and hoped that auto-complete was the solution?

Comment: Yes, auto-complete in .properties is the main idea of question.
Why does in first case it work grate, but in another my build.gradle looks like a yellow banana.
I know i can hide notification but i want to implement autocomplete like in first case.
Is it way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is that the methods in your `@Configuration` class are not public. Just add `public` to `facebook` and `facebookResource` and you'll be fine. I've just polished that doc in [c4cb8317](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/c4cb8317704add37b5d1a8070d943ecad3152578) and I've [submitted a PR to fix the tutorial](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/pull/35) you were using as a base.

Also the generated metadata were mostly empty since nested objects were not flagged with `@NestedConfigurationProperty`. I've submitted [another pull request](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/pull/36) to fix that.

Comment: Hm, as i know bean should not been private, so public is redundant, like in service interface. I am right, are not I?

Comment: No public is not redundant.

Comment: As i see you are contributor of this guide.
So take a look on this case please: 
When i use public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails facebook(), configuration-processor generate only one property: facebook.client.scope[].
I do not know why, but if i change OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails -> AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails
i see all properties in application.properties.

Comment: Also idea move OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails and ResourceServerProperties to one class does not work for me.
processor generate spring-configuration-metadata.json like
{
  "groups": [{
    "name": "facebook",
    "type": "com.deliveryteam.delivery.configuration.OAuth2Client",
    "sourceType": "com.deliveryteam.delivery.configuration.SocialConfig",
    "sourceMethod": "facebook()"
  }],
  "properties": [],
  "hints": []
}

So i have not any properties from inside classes in my application.properties. How to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Damien, it would be nice if you could focus on one problem. Answering to questions in comment is far from ideal, just create another thread. The answer is that the guide was wrong so I fixed it again: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/pull/36

Comment: Yep, but problem was dropped step by step, so i think it was a part of one main question.
Thanks a lot!